# Removing unwanted items from solr autosuggester

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, lookup, autosuggest

I am trying to implement auto suggest from a huge set of paragraphs that are indexed. But I would want to filter out certain unwanted words appearing in auto suggest. For example words like "and", "how", "when", etc needs to be avoided. How do i go about it.

This is the configuration I have done for autosuggest in solrconfig.xml..

```
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">suggest</str>
  <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
  <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>

  <str name="field">keywords</str> 
  <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
  <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>

</lst>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend adding the [StopFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StopFilterFactory) to the backing `fieldType` definition for your `keywords` field in your schema.xml file. If you need those words ("and", "how", "when") in your `keywords` field for other searching requirements, I would suggest creating a custom field in your schema.xml just for the suggester and you can use the [copyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) directive to populate this new field.